# Smart tv SDK javascript Worng paht $MANAGER_WIDGET

Tags: javascript, eclipse, samsung-smart-tv

I'm trying to create my first application for smart tv but I have a problem with the javascript.

Html

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="$MANAGER_WIDGET/Common/API/TVKeyValue.js"></script>
```

.js

```
var tvKey = new Commons.API.TVKeyValue();
```

When I run the project the error is
[JS ERROR]:
File: file://c/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Samsung/Samsung%20TV%20SDK%204/apps/_temp_20100108_/app/javascript/Main.js
Line No:        2
Error Detail:   Uncaught ReferenceError: Commons is not defined
 [JS ERROR]:
File:           file://c/Program%20Files%20(x86)/Samsung/Samsung%20TV%20SDK%204/apps/_temp_20100108_/index.html?country=US&language=1&lang=en&modelid=SDK&server=development&firmware=T-INFOLINK2013-1000&remocon=4_35_259_12&area=USA
Line No:        21

Any Help?

Edited:
What meaning of $MANAGER_WIDGET? In Eclipse, where I can change the variable path?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use keyword `Common`, not `Commons`

```
var tvKey = new Common.API.TVKeyValue();
```

`$MANAGER_WIDGET` is symbol, that substitutes by Samsung Browser in TV or Emulator to path of main widget. It contains common code for Client APIs. On Windows Emulator 2012 (from 3.5.2 SDK) replaces `$MANAGER_WIDGET` to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Samsung\Samsung TV SDK(3.5.2)\Emulator\Emulator2012_v3.5\commonlib\`

Answer (score 0):

$MANAGER_WIDGET is an environment variable for the emulator. It points to the library folder for the emulator version you are running, i.e. if you are running 2013 emulator its value is 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Samsung\Samsung TV SDK 4\Emulator\Emulator2013_v4\commonlib
for 2012 emulator its value is
C:\Program Files (x86)\Samsung\Samsung TV SDK 4\Emulator\Emulator2012_v3.5\commonlib.

Check the position of script tags in yout index.html file, you should load TvKeyValue.js before Main.js.